# How much dough will I need in order to fill a loaf tin?

Tags: baking, bread

I'm going to be making a loaf of bread in a 900 g tin (11" x 4.5" x 4" deep).

What is the total weight of the dough I will need (when mixed) for a tin this size?

Answer (score 7):

Literally speaking, a 900 g (2 lb) loaf tin is designed for a 900 g loaf.  You'll be fine if you use that much dough.

Some mass does get lost during the baking process due to evaporation, so if you want to *end up with* 900 g and not less (as an actual bakery would try to do), then you want to plan for anywhere between 8% and 12% loss, depending on the kind of dough and how long you bake it for, as well as how quickly you cool it.

The standard figure for mass loss seems to be [about 9%](http://books.google.ca/books?id=TXYIrkrtDw0C&lpg=PA310&ots=jZhlpKjHSB&dq=bread%20evaporation%2010%25&pg=PA310#v=onepage&q&f=false), plus whatever is lost during cooling - generally around 1-2%.  I would compensate 10%, meaning to use 1000 g (1 kg or 2.2 lbs) of dough.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a ruler handy, so I'm just throwing out a number here - I would think that you should be looking at about two pounds of dough.  I'm sure I will be corrected if I am too far off.